# Officer word breakline to replace multiple line text R

Tags: r, cpu-word, officer

I am using `officer` R package to replace values in a `Word` document. How to replace existing placeholder (here `place`) by a multi line text of unknown length? I have tried `\n` and `<br>` for breakline without success.

```
library(officer)
my_doc <- read_docx()
my_doc <- officer::body_add_par(my_doc, "place")

my_doc <- body_replace_all_text(my_doc, "place", "first line \n<br> next_line")
output_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")
output_file
print(my_doc, target = output_file)
```

A solution would be to split the character string in a vector. Put `place_1` to `place_max` in the word document and replace it with the right line from 1 to k and put empty strings in the remaining ones.

I am searching for a better solution. Thanks a lot for any clue.

Comment: this is not possible for now: https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/281

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your work on the package. I will do the index placeholders solution.